# reload all running zsh instances

Tags: zsh

I typically have on the order of a dozen zsh processes running. When I edit my config files, I'd like a clean way to get them all to re-initialize. Ideally, this would not mean completely killing them all and restarting as that loses my working directory, any shell variables I had set locally, temporary aliases, etc. In a given shell, I can `exec "${SHELL}"` and that works fine, but I want a way to force all active zsh instances under my login to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a trap function:

```
TRAPUSR1() {
  if [[ -o INTERACTIVE ]]; then
     {echo; echo execute a new shell instance } 1>&2
     exec "${SHELL}"
  fi
}
```

This funtion is called when the running shell catches a `USR1` signal, initiated by `kill -USR1 <PID>`. It checks if the running *zsh* instance is interactive and if so, replaces it with a new one.<sup>+</sup>

So, to update all your running zsh interactive session in one run, simply use

```
killall -USR1 zsh
```

But please be aware that if you have running zsh instances *without* the `TRAPUSR1()` function defined, these will exit upon `USR1`! That's why you should define the trap in `/etc/zshenv`, as this is the only file which is read by *every* zsh instance,<sup>+</sup> including scripts and sessions started with `zsh -f`.

---

<sup>+</sup> Credits go to @Adaephon, who pointed this out in [a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/852912/reload-all-running-zsh-instances/852935#comment1128198_852935).

Comment: There is one problem with that solution: When `zsh` is used to run a script, it does not load from `~/.zshrc`. Scripts therefore will not have a trap function for `USR1`. As the default behaviour is to terminate on `USR1`, any script running with `zsh` will be terminated when running `killall -USR1 zsh`. The only files read by every `zsh` instance are `/etc/zshenv` and `~/.zshenv`. So you would have to define the trap there. Also you would need to extend it with a check to see whether the shell is interactive and only then run `exec "${SHELL}"`.

Comment: @Adaephon: Thanks, two valid points, I included them in my answer. Only some nitpicking here: "The only files read by every zsh instance are /etc/zshenv and ~/.zshenv". This is true only for `/etc/zshenv`, sourcing of `~/.zshenv` depends also on `RCS` and `PRIVILEGED` options.

Comment: On multi-user machines (or if you have system scripts using zsh) you may want to include `-u $(whoami)` in your killall command. Otherwise you will get `Operation not permitted` errors for other users' zsh instances.